# Mat select not displaying value correctly angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

Mat select not displaying value correctly 
Here is my code

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="empData" placeholder="Employee" [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let v of emp" [value]="v.name">{{v.name}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

its not displaying any thing.
if I access like this

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="empData" placeholder="Employee" [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let v of emp" [value]="v[0].name">{{v[0].name}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Its giving one value
If I access like this

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="empData" placeholder="Employee" [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let v of emp" [value]="v[1].name">{{v[1].name}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

its giving the second value, please suggest how to access dynamically.
here is my ts code

```
getProject() {
  this.configs.getEmp().subscribe(data => {
    this.pro = data['employee'];
    this.emp = this.pro.map(o => {
      return {id: o.eid, name: o.ename};          
    });           
  },           
  err => console.error(err),            
  () => console.log('done loading emp'));        
}
```

Comment: What does this.emp look like?

Comment: Your code samples do not fit. The `getProject()` implies that `this.emp` is an array of objects. in your HTML examples and based in your description it appears to be that `this.emp` is an array of arrays of objects. So the issue probably is in other parts of your code.

Comment: thank for the response, could you please guide me any better way to achieve this.